# pandas Panel 'iterrows' (iterate through major axis)

Tags: python, pandas, iterator

I have a `pandas` Panel that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
P = pd.Panel(np.arange(90).reshape(5,6,3))
```

I want to create an generator along the major axis, similar to `pd.DataFrame.iterrows`, so that at each call, `next` returns a tuple containing the current major axis index and a `pd.DataFrame` of shape `(P.shape[0], P.shape[2])`. Is this functionality already available in `pandas`? If not, is there a way to use `pd.DataFrame.iterrows` or `numpy` iterators to efficiently replicate this functionality?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do this:

```
for m, df in P.to_frame().unstack().iterrows():
    print m
    print df.unstack()
```

Better still:

```
for i, item in P.swapaxes(0, 1).iteritems():
    print i
    print item
```

#### Solution

```
P.swapaxes(0, 1).iteritems()
```

Answer (score 2):

is that what you want?

```
In [176]: [i for i in P.iteritems()]
Out[176]:
[(0,     0   1   2
  0   0   1   2
  1   3   4   5
  2   6   7   8
  3   9  10  11
  4  12  13  14
  5  15  16  17), (1,     0   1   2
  0  18  19  20
  1  21  22  23
  2  24  25  26
  3  27  28  29
  4  30  31  32
  5  33  34  35), (2,     0   1   2
  0  36  37  38
  1  39  40  41
  2  42  43  44
  3  45  46  47
  4  48  49  50
  5  51  52  53), (3,     0   1   2
  0  54  55  56
  1  57  58  59
  2  60  61  62
  3  63  64  65
  4  66  67  68
  5  69  70  71), (4,     0   1   2
  0  72  73  74
  1  75  76  77
  2  78  79  80
  3  81  82  83
  4  84  85  86
  5  87  88  89)]
```

or:

```
In [174]: [print(i[1]) for i in P.iteritems()]
    0   1   2
0   0   1   2
1   3   4   5
2   6   7   8
3   9  10  11
4  12  13  14
5  15  16  17
    0   1   2
0  18  19  20
1  21  22  23
2  24  25  26
3  27  28  29
4  30  31  32
5  33  34  35
    0   1   2
0  36  37  38
1  39  40  41
2  42  43  44
3  45  46  47
4  48  49  50
5  51  52  53
    0   1   2
0  54  55  56
1  57  58  59
2  60  61  62
3  63  64  65
4  66  67  68
5  69  70  71
    0   1   2
0  72  73  74
1  75  76  77
2  78  79  80
3  81  82  83
4  84  85  86
5  87  88  89
Out[174]: [None, None, None, None, None]
```